# ng-click and ng-change both not calling the function for CHECKBOX

Tags: angularjs

```
<div id="funds">
    <table border="0" style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="parent in vm.fundList">
                <td align="left" valign="top" colspan="6">
                    <span style="display:inline-block;background-color:#EBEBEB;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;width:100%;">
                        <input ng-model="parent.ParentID" id='parent.ParentID' ng-click="vm.SelectAllFunds(parent.ParentID)" type="checkbox" >
                        <label>{{parent.ParentFundName}}</label>
                    </span>
                </td>



                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <span style="display:inline-block;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;width:100%;">
                        <input id="child + parent.ChildFund.ChildID" type="checkbox" value=" parent.ChildFund.ChildFundName" name=" parent.ChildFund.ChildFundName" ng-click="vm.checkFund(parent.ChildFund.ChildID)">
                        <label>{{parent.ChildFund.ChildFundName}} </label>
                    </span>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

</div>
```

ng-click and ng-change tried both but both are not working for checkboxes which are generated dynamically using ng-repeat.

Comment: can you post some of your controller code where you define the functions you're trying to call?  also, not sure if it would affect your problem, but are you sure that your input id attributes are valid?

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/qy3MJYNbpmwv7npe4k8M?p=info. Something must be wrong in your JS code. Post a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ng-checked like this:

```
<INPUT
    ng-checked="expression">
    ...
</INPUT>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked